# Linking generated library using autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools, static-linking

I have a following directory structure

```
src/
    kernel/
    gui/
```

In kernel/ directory, I have generated a library named `libkernel.a` and in gui/ directory I have to use `libkernel.a` to generate `libgui.a`.

I added this to the gui/Makefile.am

```
libgui_a_LIBADD = $(srcdir)/kernel/libkernel.a
```

But I am getting the following error

```
*** No rule to make target `kernel/libkernel.a', needed by `libgui.a'.  Stop.
```

So I don't understand how do I link `libkernel.a` properly.

**Edit/Explanation**

In gui/ directory I have one `somegui.cpp` file that uses `xclass.h` which is in kernel/ directory.
So in order to solve that issue I am asking how should I proceed.

Comment: If you're going to use the autotools, it's best to build [*libtool* libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Libtool-Concept), and let libtool take care of the linking - static or otherwise. Start by adding the variables for: `libkernel.la`.

Comment: I am creating the library as this. See my edited question. I don't want to give relative address of `xclass.h` in the `somegui.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use non-recursive automake to avoid these kind of problems.

https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/nonrecursive.html

Sidenode: use $(top_builddir) when referring to compiled objects. Otherwise your code will break when srcdir != builddir

If you really have to do it recursive, than you can add a rule to gui/Makefile.am

```
$(top_builddir)/kernel/libkernel.a:
        cd $(top_builddir)/kernel && $(MAKE)
```

Note: If you want to use parallel make (-j) you also need to make sure that in src/Makefile.am there is a dependency between the subdirs

```
.PHONY kernel gui
kernel:
      cd kernel && $(MAKE)
gui: kernel
      cd gui && $(MAKE)
```

Comment: That's a good advice but I kind of have to do this in a recursive way. :/

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a recursive solution